# Creating new user on Office admin portal not syncing to Dynamics CRM online

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-crm-online

I created "Microsoft 365 Business Demo Content" using https://demo.microsoft.com portal. I created solution and entities on the CRM using "MOD administrator" account.

I am trying to test using another user, so I created user from https://portal.office.com/ portal. I assigned "Microsoft 365 Business, Dynamics 365 P1 Trial for Information Workers" license to the user. But the user is not syncing to the Dynamics CRM under Settings -> Security -> Users page. I could not also add a new user, which redirect to the office admin page.

Please let me know how to get the new user created on office admin portal to Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have followed all the steps listed out [here](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/add-dynamics-crm-license-new-office-365-users/).

In O365 portal, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online **Basic** or **Professional** license has to be assigned to particular user, then only that user will be replicated to CRM (FYI, CRM *Portal* is totally different).

[image]

[Read this](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/762/t/249212) if you are stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Arun. I was validating this issue more, I understand in demo/trial tenant, the user is not syncing automatically. I added the user into "Add colleagues" from the Help menu. After adding the user, I could able to get the user to the environment. Later I assigned to a security role and used.
[image]